# Mass resize album art files attached to mp3 files

Tags: mp3

I have around 1,000 mp3 files all sorted into different folders. All of them have JPEG album art files embedded that are 640x640. I need to resize all of them to be 500x500.

Anyone have any recommendations on software/tools to do this? I have been manually doing this inside of foobar2000 and it is taking awhile.

Comment: We do not entertain questions asking for software recommendations. Please read the Help section to better understand how this site works, then use the EDIT button and fix your question if you are able.

Comment: Please post this on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Download and install [IrfanView](https://www.irfanview.com/)
2. Launch IrfanView and immediately press "B" (batch conversion)

[image]

3. Tick "use advanced options (for bulk resize...) > Click Advanced

[image]

4. Set your custom RESIZE settings like so > then click OK

[image]

5. Use the file browser (box above) to navigate to your folder containing all the JPGs. You can use "Add" to add a single or a selection of files (box below). Or you can use "Add All" to add every file inside a directory.

[image]

6. Set your output folder to your specification. There is also a setting to put the converted file back into the source folder it came from.

[image]

7. Click "Start Batch"

Tip: If drag drop does not work in this version you may wish to try [v4.42 here](https://www.filepuma.com/download/irfanview_64bit_4.42-10910/) which should work in Windows 10. There have been reports of drag drop not working in the input box on the latest version.

I mention this because you say your JPGs are in many sub-folders. So your best approach sounds like you'll want to search the top folder for .jpg and then drag all the resulting files into the input box for batch conversion, making sure "Use current look in folder" is selected so all the converted files go back to the source folders they came from.

Comment: Are you sure this will work with images **INSIDE** mp3 files?

Comment: the OP doesn't have JPGs. They have album art in the mp3 files

Comment: No, i think you would have to extrapolate those images from the mp3 files, batch convert them and then burn the converted images back into the mp3s.